# Loading HTML form page inside document.createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Below I have an example section from a javascript site I've been editing. I need to load a HTML form inside this section. How do I embed a html form (../form.html) into this? Or is there a better way to create forms utilizing JS?

```
this.display_admin_table_header = function () {

    current_pane.send_get_admin_table_data = this.send_get_admin_table_data;
    $('#admin_tab').addClass('selected');
    $('#stat_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
    var test =  $(document.createElement('p'));
    test.append("test string test string test string"
    );

    $('#stat_table').append(test);
    }
```

The HTML form is just composed of things like this (nothing fancy, but displays find by itself in a browser:

```
    <label class="description" for="element_1">Node </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_2" >
    <label class="description" for="element_2">Site-Bucket </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use jQuery.get() to get the html from the html form page

```
$.get( "ajax/form-page.html", function( data ) {
  //here you have acess to the html form the form page
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

jQuery.get() is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Another option is use jquery´s load function

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div2").load("form.html");
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="div1"><h2>jQuery AJAX Load</h2></div>
    <div id="div2"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
    <button>Get External Content</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I tried the .get function. I can see the file being called and loaded but nothing is displayed. If I just load the form page in a browser it shows the form I created.

Comment: can you post the code you used with jquery.get() and/or the full html where the form html is being appended?

Comment: `this.display_admin_table_header = function () {

        current_pane.send_get_admin_table_data =    this.send_get_admin_table_data;
        $('#admin_tab').addClass('selected');
        $('#stat_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
       $.get( "form1.html", function( data ) {
       $( ".result" ).html( data ); 
       });
//     $('#stat_table').result;
        } `

Comment: Ok. Well, now i tryed using load function and it worked. I edited my answer and posted the code sample.

Comment: turns out this works too: $('#stat_table').load('form1.html');